# Insert span around highlighted/selected text without selection.extractContents()?

Tags: jquery

I want to insert `span` tags around select text in a `contenteditable` `<div>`. Here's what I currently have:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.button', function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
});
```

It does the job, but the issue with using `selection.extractContents()` is that it removes selection (`e.preventDefault()` allows to keep the text selected when clicking the `.button`).

Is there a way to achieve this without using `selection.extractContents()`?